# How to get the pc or dc from a tag using regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

In a page there are many times this tag

```
<div class="clsfd_thumb_container pc">
```

and this tag

```
<div class="clsfd_thumb_container dc">
```

the only difference is the `pc` and `dc`

What I want to do is to save in an array all `pc` or `dc` matched and echo them.

The only thing I need is the regex to match all the `pc` and `dc`.

How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: This is waaay to specific a regex question. You should edit it to fix a more generic purpose.If you search stack overflow, you will find a ton of questions that would have helped you if you had tried anything before posting

Comment: I'd recommend you instead pass by an extra step and using javascript and the DOM for selecting all elements with the class you're looking for (dc/pc).. Maybe an intermediate step to your final solution but at least it's much less error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
[pd]c(?=">)
```

- `[pd]`: Matches `p` or `d`.
- `c`: Well matches `c` of course.
- `(?=">)`: It onles matches what I have listed above if they are followed by `"` then a `>`.

In PHP you can use [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/function.preg-match-all) to extract all of the matches, passing the regular expression above as a string in the first parameter.

```
preg_match_all('/[pd]c(?=">)/', $str, $dealers);
                ^           ^
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uN2yM0)

Comment: Hi there, and thank you for this. I used this `preg_match_all('[pd]c(?=">)', $str, $dealers);` but I got a `Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'c' `

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex really, you could just use `strpos`

```
if(strpos($div_tag, 'dc') || strpos($div_tag, 'pc')) {
    $array[] = $div_tag;
}
```